# How to pass parameters to JSP using response.sendRedirect?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I really need to use `response.sendRedirect()` method because my JSP(search.jsp)  page is actually calling for a servlet `<jsp:include page="/searchServlet" />` and in my `searchServlet` if I use the forward method (to the same page) I get a weird error (maybe because I'm calling it and forwarding all the time, I din't find the reason yet..) however I need to read an attribute in my JSP(search.jsp)  page with a simple message like "Please provide valid data"

However since I'm using my response to redirect to a page, and set this attribute in my request scope, when I try to read it nothing will as expected. I tried to put this attribute in my Session Scope, read and then removing it, it worked (passing wrong data), but only for the first time, if I try to run it providing all data correctly again I'll get the error message since I dind't close my browser to actually remove it from my Session.

So my question is: there is a way to use `sendRedirect()` and set an attribute to my JSP page together? If not, how to solve this problem?

Thank you!

**EDIT 1:**

searchServlet:

```
if (errorMessage != null) {
    /*sendError will generate an HTML error page using the message that you supplied and will override the content type to text/html.
    response.sendError(1, errorMessage);    
    */
    request.getSession().setAttribute("errorMessage",errorMessage);
    response.sendRedirect("charts/search.jsp");
}
```

search.JSP

```
<jsp:include page="/searchServlet" /> 
<c:if test="${sessionScope.errorMessage != null}">
    <div id="error-Message">
        <c:out value="${sessionScope.errorMessage}" />
        <c:remove var="errorMessage" scope="session" />
    </div>
</c:if>
```

**EDIT 2:**
The error I get if I use the forward() instead of sendRedirect and I never stops, keep looping:

```
at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:390)
// the error above repeats for more than a thousand times   

at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:390)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.unwrapRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:846)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:822)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
at control.SearchCriteriaServlet.doPost(SearchCriteriaServlet.java:99)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
at org.apache.jsp.charts.searchChart_jsp._jspService(searchChart_jsp.java:183)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**EDIT 3:**

My doGet() method:

```
ArrayList<Machine> foundMachines = MachineDB.getAllMachines();
request.setAttribute("foundMachineList", foundMachines);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/searchServlet");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

My doPost() that process all entries and have inside it my code from edit1:

Comment: Can you show the forward() code you have written

Comment: the forward() I'm not using, but here it is `RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("charts/chartView.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);`

Comment: What problem you are facing if you use forward()?

Comment: I just posted the error for you

Comment: Why does your JSP page contain a jsp:include to your servlet- what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: what does the searchServlet do actually?why you need <jsp:include> here

Comment: I have a dropdownlist that is populated by DB results, so I put it there to call the servlet and then populate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got the REASON why you are facing the problem. That because infinite call loop. See the code you have written.
In your JSP `<jsp:include page="/searchServlet" />`  this line causes to call your servlet `searchServlet` and again in the servlet you sending the request to `search.JSP`. So correct the issue now.

Comment: You can add more than one answer,but preferably you should delete one before posting the other.That's a good habit! Also,if you aren't sure about anything,please mention details in the comment.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted old one.

Comment: but I put this include code because I have a dropdownlist that is populated by DB results, so I put it there to call this servlet and then populate it

Comment: In your searchServlet pull list of data from DB and put in request, forward() request to search.JSP, now you can populate list in JSP , thats all

Comment: refer this http://www.java-forums.org/javaserver-pages-jsp-jstl/36630-dynamically-populate-dropdown-box-using-jsp.html

Answer (score 1):

As you have found, you can't pass an attribute in the request if you are doing a redirect, as the redirect causes the browser to issue a new request. So the request (object) you'll have in your JSP page will be a new one- not the one in which you stored the attribute.

You can store attributes in the session, but as you have found this can cause problems if you don't reset/remove them between requests. Storing state in the session can also cause problems if a user uses their browser's 'back' button, or has two or more tabs open at once.

You can pass information in a request parameter using a redirect- eg by constructing the URL you are redirecting to so that it contains the parameters. 
For example blahblah/search?message=whatever

However, this can look weird to the user (they will see the parameters in their browser's address bar) and you may run into problems of the URLs become large.

In your case I would look at why the forward is not working.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by mahesh, you have a general design problem :

- `search.jsp` includes `searchServlet` (hmm ...)
- `searchServlet` forwards (or redirect as a workaround) to `search.jsp`

That design is pretty uncommon. Of course using a redirect instead or a forward in you servlet will break the infinite loop, but your servlet sends the redirect to the browser so that the browser calls the view ... and of course you cannot pass anything in the request between the servlet and its view since the view will be called in another request ... IMHO the redirect here is only a quick workaround.

What would be better (according to common practices)

- browser initially calls the servlet (ie : the link to search page points to an url directly processed by the servlet)
- the servlet does the heavy work (programmed in java, simpler to write and test)
- the servlet puts all relevant parameters in request and forward to a jsp
- the jsp simply formats all in good html that will be displayed in the browser.

Comment: but I tried to do this and got that error, I wanted to use the same servlet and page to do all the work where the doGet() only creates an ArrayList and put it back to the same page to populate my dropdownlist and my doPost() to process all entry and validate it

Comment: @migmig From the browser you do not ask `/.../charts/search.jsp` but directly `/.../searchServlet` and you do not include `searchServlet` from `search.jsp`. Then you can forward form the servlet to the jsp.

Comment: I removed my include tag and changed my forward page to my servlet however it keeps looping N times and then the same error

Comment: If servlet calls jsp and jsp do not call servlet, it cannot loop. Please show your present code.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear enough, in my index page I also call my servlet to populate this dropdownlist, If i just call the search.jsp page it won't loop, however if I do call this servlet using the get method it will

Comment: The `doGet` in your Edit3 is not in the same servlet , is it ? If a servlet forward to itself you do have an infinite loop. The rule is : browser => servlet => jsp => html

Comment: yes it is, i was trying to use the same servlet to handle the `doGet` to populate my dropdownlist and my `doPost`to validade the entries and redirect to other page

Comment: but since i'm getting this infinite loop I think I'll create another servlet to create the values to populate this dropdownlist and redirect to this page, and this page call my `searchServlet` and validates the entries, if they are'nt valid call the first servlet again...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56355/discussion-between-serge-ballesta-and-migmig).

Answer (score 0):

You can keep parameters in session.

```
session.setAttribute("Att1","para1");
session.setAttribute("Att2","para2");
.
.
.
```

like this.

Comment: I did that, and worked, but since the browser wasn't closed I was still getting the same error message

Answer (score -1):

you can use RequestDispatcher like this:-

```
     RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");
     rd.forward(request,response);
```

if you are using response.sendRedirect then you can add the parameters in the ServletRequest Object,and can be use in jsp.like that:-

```
      <% String st=(String)request.getParameter("uname"); %>
```