# Spring Boot + Spring Security + Custom filter(siteminder) - Infinte Loop

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to configure a custom security filter for my Spring Boot webapp. Initially I configured it to custom form login from Angular JS, but now I am trying to detach that config and implement the Siteminder SSO filter. I am using RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter provided by Spring. I will post the config too. But when I add this config it goes into an infinite loop when I pull up my webapp after the server is started. Here is the infinite loop. Please let me know if you want to look at additional config or details, but this has been haunting me since a week. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks !

```
======================Infinite Loop Start=========================

[ERROR] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/mpe].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    ====================================624 Times Start=============================================
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:390) ~[servlet-api.jar:3.0.FR]
    =====================================624 Times End============================================

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.unwrapRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:846) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]

    ====================================40Times Start====================
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:155) ~[spring-boot-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:138) ~[spring-boot-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:89) ~[spring-boot-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.55]
    ====================================40 Times End===========================================

    ====================================Infinite Loop End============================================
```

Answer (score 2):

I see from the stack trace that Spring Boot's `ErrorPageFilter` is involved in the infinite loop and that you're using version 1.1.3.RELEASE of Spring Boot. A [change was made](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/4a33ab557721cc3d25583e246bf4b5d9173c15c8) in Spring Boot 1.1.5 to ensure that its `ErrorPageFilter` is only driven once per request. You should upgrade to the latest version of Spring Boot (1.1.8.RELEASE at the time of writing). It'll either resolve your problem completely, or allow you to see the underlying problem once the infinite loop's out of the way.

Comment: Dude! you are a savior !! Creously Thanks a ton ! I wish I had posted this way earlier instead of banging my head around it !

Answer (score 1):

The infinite loop is due to an incorrect configuration.  Some common causes:

- If you have an "access denied" page, it should NOT be protected with your security filter.  Otherwise, the security filter will be invoked infinitely.
- If you're using JSPs or another templating technology, check that you don't have [infinitely recursive includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409860/how-to-pass-parameters-to-jsp-using-response-sendredirect).